# Для input убрать required но оставить :valid

Tags: html, css, css3

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если для `input` убрать `required` то `:valid` становится активным при пустом `input`

```css
.test {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  transition: .4s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  transition: .4s;
  resize: none;

}

input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<div class="form-field">
  <input name="" type="text" required>
  <label class="form-label">Enter changes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
  <input name="" type="text">
  <label class="form-label">Enter changes (не работает)</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Что мне нужно: Это исправить второй пример, который исключает для `input required` 
`:valid` мне нужно для того чтобы при заполнении `input` `label` не возвращался обратно
Думаю пояснил проблему..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать такой *хак*: добавить необязательному полю `pattern=""`, и затем в `optional:invalid` делать всю магию. Минус: `pattern=""` нужно будет добавлять к каждому необязательному полю.

```css
.test {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  transition: .4s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  transition: .4s;
  resize: none;
}

input:focus~label,
input:required:valid~label,
input:optional:invalid~label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="form-field">
    <input name="" type="text" required>
    <label class="form-label">Enter changes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input name="" type="text" pattern="">
    <label class="form-label">Enter changes (не работает)</label>
  </div>
</div>
```